# Meaning of "shot" cloth

Tags: meaning, literature

> "A truly beautiful shade! A cloth of smoked grey, shot with flame colour!"

—Gogol, trans. by D. J. Hogarth

'Shot' is what is confusing me. In my mind I imagine it refers to a repeated pattern. My best guess as to what it would look like is this, on the right:

[image: Image of silk scarves]

Comment: The page you link to doesn't show anything *in my browser* like what you are talking about. Sometimes web links, especially to online shops, don't transfer well between computers; it would be better to use an image, if you think one would be helpful.

Comment: Was just doing that...

Comment: slowlikemolasses, I appreciate your effort at presenting the question in good detail. However, you should have put in as much effort at finding an answer or at least some leads, rather than 'imagining' and 'guessing'. On ELU, askers need to show some background research.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Shot in ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shot--2)

> **1** (of coloured cloth) woven with a warp and weft of different colours, giving a contrasting effect when looked at from different angles:
>   *a dress of shot silk*
>   - interspersed with a different colour: *dark hair shot with silver*
>   - (shot through with) suffused with (a particular feature or quality): *the mist was shot through with orange spokes of light*

It's not a repeated pattern; it's a highlight of some sort, either the odd thread, or the entire warp or weft.

In the quote, it could be either, but since a different warp and weft would give rise to "a truly beautiful shade," it's probably that: woven throughout with two different colours.

I couldn't find an example of grey and red, but here's blue and red from the blog [Snoring Scholar](http://snoringscholar.com/2011/03/the-paradoxes-of-christianity-thoughts-on-orthodoxy/blue-w_red-shot-silk-dupioni-fabric696/):

[image: Shot silk]

Comment: You might be able to figure out which it actually means by looking at the original Russian.

Comment: From the Robert Maguire translation: "A splendid hue. Cloth of Navarino smoke and flame." This sounds like your guess is right. And "smoke and flame" definitely sounds more symbolic (of something) that "smoked grey shot with flame colour".

Comment: Yes, "smoke and flame" could indicate that they were of equal quantity, and weaving with the two colours would produce a lustrous colour. Navarino is Pylos in the Peloponnese: do/did they make cloth in a particular way there?

Comment: There was also a battle of Navarino, in which Russia was involved, and where dense smoke was present.

Comment: The original Russian is "[Вот-с сукно-с! цвету наваринского дыму с пламенем](http://www.100bestbooks.info/txt2/?act=3&page=117)", *Vot-s sukno-s! Tsvjetu navarinskovo dymu s planjenjem*, which is literally "Here's the cloth! The color of Navarino, smoke with flames!" @PeterShor, this does refer to the battle. I suspect the choice of the word "shot" was a bit of translation double-entendre.

Comment: Thanks everybody! I'm still having trouble picturing a cloth that "giv[es] a contrasting effect when looked at from different angles" with the use of a "warp and weft of different colours." A blue warp and a white weft would produce an overall color of pale blue; I don't see how that would change from a different angle. I can see distance changing one's perception of the color, but not angle. Any examples?

Comment: @slowlikemolasses Found an example of something similar.

Comment: @slowlikemolasses(inJanuary?): [Here](https://dawnsdressdiary.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/silk-flowers/) is an entry in a sewing blog where you can see pictures of the effect of different angles with shot fabric. I guess from some angles you see more of the warp and others more of the weft.

Comment: @slowlikemolasses: Fabric is three-dimensional - there are threads that are lower down and threads that are higher up. Thus, you don't always see the warp and the weft equally. (In fact, there are weaves where you only see one or the other.) This is why some fabrics can appear to be different colors depending on your angle of view.

Comment: Mark, how likely is it that specificity was sacrificed to make the allusion? Is there a word in Russian with the same meaning as "shot" has here? Would this way of sowing have been common at that time?

Comment: @slowlikemolasses: in the Maguire translation, before choosing the smoke and flame cloth Chichikov asks the merchant "Do you have any cloth of whortleberry colours shot with silver?" So if this is an accurate translation, then "smoke shot with flame" may be an excellent description of the Navarino colour cloth.

Comment: @PeterShor. Good catch. In the Russian, that whorlteberry shot with silver was "больше искрасна, чтобы искры были." *bol'shje iskrasna, chtoby iskry byli*, literally "more reddish, with sparks in it". Except the term for "reddish", искрасна, is considered an obsolete word. Again, no reference to anything like "shot", but rather to sparks or fire.

Comment: @Mark: So "whortleberry" (confusing, since whortleberries can be either red or blue) was introduced by the translater? We have earlier in the two translations I can search online: "... then he posted himself in front of the mirror, donned a false shirt-front, plucked out a couple of hairs protruding from his nose, and appeared vested in a frock-coat of bilberry-colored check" and "Then he donned his shirt-front before the mirror, plucked two hairs protruding from his nose, and directly thereafter appeared in a tail-coat of whortleberry red shot with a lighter weave." Aren't bilberries blue?